# Angular Page automatically redirects to parent state when refreshed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, route-provider

Whenever I refresh the page it goes to the parent state.I have given my code snippet.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider  
.state('home', {        
    url:'/',        
    templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.html',      
}).state('home.addcrew', {
  url: '/addcrew',
  templateUrl: 'modules/crew/addCrew.html',      

})
```

How to retain my current page on refresh? Can Anyone please help me

Comment: What URL do you see in browser?

Comment: you can store some values in localstorage and  check condition before `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`

Comment: write the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');` at the end. You have not allowed to check for the state from `$stateProvider`.

Comment: @MaximShoustin It shows the base url on refresh in browser.

Comment: @AgamBanga I tried.but getting same result

Comment: @scary_devil : but localstorage value remains even after browser shutdown right?

Comment: yes @Riyash.D you can create a variable and update it based on the user sign-in and sign-out or whatever the condition you want to.

Comment: Found any solution? I'm stuck with the same issue. On refresh, the url too changes to parent url

Answer (score 0):

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jWoIMHBsPj0I79je1uq1?p=preview).

What we need, is to instruct UI-Router about child's special url. It is special, because parent contains `"/"` and with child part `"/addcrew"` would end up in **`//addcrew`**.

But we want child to re-start url *(not use parent part)* - we can do it with **`^`** sign:

```
$stateProvider  
    .state('home', {        
    url:'/',
    ...
}).state('home.addcrew', {
    url: '^/addcrew',
    ...
})
```

Check it in action here

- http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/jWoIMHBsPj0I79je1uq1/#/addcrew